# Agrupar parcelas mostrando o valor da primeira e da última parcela

Tags: postgresql

Tenho uma tabela de parcelas com os seguintes campos (entre outros): `inscricao` (Inscrição do Cliente), `nrparcela` (Número da Parcela), `dt_vencimento` (Data de Vencimento) e `vlrparcela` (Valor da Parcela).

Se o cliente tiver 10 parcelas, haverá 10 registros na tabela com a coluna `nrparcela` numerada de 1 a 10, com as respectivas datas de vencimento e valores (variados) para aquele cliente.

Como agrupar esses registros, selecionando o número da primeira parcela (geralmente '1'), o número da última parcela, o valor da primeira parcela e o valor da última parcela?

O valor de cada parcela pode variar, havendo casos onde o valor de cada parcela é diferente dos demais valores daquele parcelamento.

Consegui apenas isso:

```
SELECT inscricao, MIN(nrparcela) AS primeira_parcela, 
       MAX(nrparcela) AS ultima_parcela
  FROM parcelas 
 GROUP BY inscricao 
 ORDER BY inscricao
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui está a minha solução:

Estrutura:

```
create table PARCELA (
  inscricao int not null,
  nrparcela int not null,
  dt_vencimento datetime,
  vlrparcela decimal(15,2)
);

alter table PARCELA add constraint PARCELA_PK primary key (inscricao, nrparcela);


insert into PARCELA values (1, 1, '2014/01/01', 10.01);
insert into PARCELA values (1, 2, '2014/01/02', 10.02);
insert into PARCELA values (1, 3, '2014/01/03', 10.03);
insert into PARCELA values (1, 4, '2014/01/04', 10.04);

insert into PARCELA values (2, 1, '2014/02/01', 110.01);
insert into PARCELA values (2, 2, '2014/02/02', 110.02);
insert into PARCELA values (2, 3, '2014/02/03', 110.03);
insert into PARCELA values (2, 4, '2014/02/04', 110.04);
insert into PARCELA values (2, 5, '2014/02/05', 110.05);
```

SQL

```
select
  a.inscricao, min(a.nrparcela), 
  (select b.vlrparcela from PARCELA b where b.inscricao = a.inscricao and b.nrparcela = min(a.nrparcela)),
  max(a.nrparcela), 
  (select b.vlrparcela from PARCELA b where b.inscricao = a.inscricao and b.nrparcela = max(a.nrparcela))
from 
  PARCELA a  
group by
  a.inscricao
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/23410f

Usei SQL Server pois não lembro dos tipos no postgresql

Answer (score 1):

As subconsultas correlacionadas (consultas dentro da lista do `select`) podem ser muito ruins para o desempenho. Então é melhor umas das duas soluções a seguir.

A primeira usando `distinct on`

```
select *
from 
    (
        select distinct on (inscricao)
            inscricao, nrparcela as primeira_parcela, vlr_parcela as vlr_primeira_parcela
        from parcelas
        order by inscricao, primeira_parcela
    ) p
    inner join
    (
        select distinct on (inscricao)
            inscricao, nrparcela as ultima_parcela, vlr_parcela as vlr_ultima_parcela
        from parcelas
        order by inscricao, ultima_parcela desc
    ) u using (inscricao)
```

A segunda com duas junções

```
select s.inscricao,
    primeira_parcela, p.vlrparcela as vlr_primeira_parcela,
    ultima_parcela, u.vlrparcela as vlr_ultima_parcela
from
    (
        select inscricao, max(nrparcela) as ultima_parcela, min(nrparcela) as primeira_parcela
        from parcelas
        group by inscricao
    ) s
    inner join
    parcelas p on p.inscricao = s.inscricao and p.nrparcela = s.primeira_parcela
    inner join
    parcelas u on u.inscricao = s.inscricao and u.nrparcela = s.ultima_parcela
```

Só testando para ver qual tem melhor desempenho